# Outside hose bibb with very fine thread?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, hose

I'm in a newly purchased house built 1998.  It has three outside hose bibbs, two are standard garden hose thread but one has a very fine thread that does not match either "Hose" or "Pipe" thread.  I looked at Home Depot and they have all sorts of adapters for various types of threads, but nothing matching this.

Here's a picture showing the hose bibb next to a standard hose thread.

What is this thread, and what kind of adapter do I need?

[image]

Comment: Use a tape measure or a ruler next to the threads so we can get an accurate thread count. Getting an idea of what it is can help us figure out where it is needed for or what it was supposed to be used but it is hard to tell from the photo.

Comment: A photo showing the full hose bibb may help somebody recognize what it is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you see there is a vacuum breaker spigot with its pants down. You'll need to try and procure the parts or just replace the whole works.

[image]

[More on that](https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/outside-faucet-has-wrong-thread-size-pipe-threads-vs-hose-threads.29260/)

Comment: Exactly correct. They deliberately use an incompatible thread because you are supposed to have a vacuum breaker on there...

Comment: Spot-on isher. You’re a good go-to guy.

Comment: The prior owner probably (unknowingly) unscrewed the vacuum breaker with the hose and left it on the hose. That person has probably taken the hose to their new house and is probably about to post a new question here, "why does my hose not screw on to a normal hose bib?"

Comment: We were missing one on our house and the only place I could find a replacement was a local small hardware store (Ace hardware in my area).  They stocked the ones that most homebuilders in the area were using and the big home stores had moved on to the newer brands and styles.  My point is check smaller stores or specialty plumbing supply places if you have trouble finding it.

Comment: @dwizum, the set screw you see in the second picture is designed to tighten and snap off in a lot of faucets.  This is so you _can't_ accidentally remove them.  Not all designs have this, but they normally have a set screw of some kind to keep them in place.

Comment: The purpose of big box stores is not to carry specialty things like that.  They mean for you to go to them for 99% of what you buy, and go to the local ACE for the odd ducks like this.  Of course, this will invoke the *tragedy of the commons*...

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer.  I found a vacuum breaker with the correct thread pitch at the local big-box store.  It was rather expensive at US$29.  The previous owners of the house seem to have been clueless in quite a few areas including this.  They had forced on a regular thread hose, which leaked profusely of course.  Luckily they didn't damage the threads on the bibb enough to prevent the vacuum breaker from screwing on.  It's all working great now.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a 3/4 national pipe thread(npt) ...most hardware stores have a conversion coupling to get to male hose thread (mpt)..ask for a 3/4 female iron pipe to male hose adaptor ...some of the hose bibs out there have decorative spout features that change the thread.
hose bib vacumn breakers are usually the same thread fht x mht they can be added after market to a hose bib unless it came from factory pre installed they are usually permanently affixed.