# What type of threads are on my spigot?

Tags: spigot

My home had these self draining spigots.

[image]

However last year I added a concrete patio which forced me to remove the head.

[image]

now it has some propriety thread and I cant put a normal 90 on it to put a hose to it.  Any suggestions other then completely replacing the spigot.
Maybe some kind of really short converter.

Comment: Usually threads are not proprietary(made by one company only) but are a type.  Different types will not fit together well.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/178262/25178 or at least it might provide additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That fitting is a vacuum breaking fitting that prevents liquid being sucked up the hose and introduced into the household plumbing system. I believe in some places those are required on newly constructed homes but most older homes don't have them.

You need something like this if you want to preserve the "non-siphon" capability, or you can get an adapter without that that just facilitates the difference in threads for a little less money:

[image: anti-vacuum fitting example]
[image: thread adapter example]

Lots of buying choices:
https://www.google.com/search?q=fine+thread+hose+bib

Comment: thank you, you have no idea how many people told me this doesnt exist (the small adapter).  of course i haven't tried it yet (just ordered it).  but im hoping so!!

Comment: All this stuff is best purchased from a "brick-and-mortar" hardware store where you can try out all the pieces together to make sure they're going to fit together, etc. The problem is many people go to BigBox stores instead to face limited product options and sales staff with potentially very limited experience and/or poor training.